# Javascript Error: Expected ':'

Tags: javascript

There seems to be something wrong with my code.
I am not too sure what the problem is as I am not very experienced with Javascript.

I'm getting this error:

> main.js Line 249: Expected `:'

This is the snippet of code:

```
function unpack(str) {
    var bytes = [];
    var len=str.length;
    for(var i = 0, n = len; i < n; i++) {
        var char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(char >>> 8, char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

I'm a total newbie so maybe the context isnt good enough. 
Thanks for all replies! :)

Comment: What is in your variable `str`?

Comment: theres nothing wrong with the code you've given it works so the problem is from something else

Comment: sometimes js exceptions do not tell you the right line. Try find the right line by inserting console.log or breakpoints inside your code

Comment: your for loop, you have used comma and isn't the error pretty clear? Expected `';'`

Comment: The code works fine.

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay That's a perfectly valid line; it means he's defining multiple statements inside that for loop's initialization. Any of the three parts supports multiple statements followed by commas.

Comment: You need to add the rest of your code. The code, as it is, is working fine.

Comment: Why do you need this `n = len`?, why don't you just replace `i < n` with `i < len` ?

Comment: `char` is a reserved keyword, in older specifications of Javascript as you can [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). This may cause problems depending on where you executive you code.

Comment: It works great. I don't see any errors.

Comment: Which line is your line 249?

Answer (score 0):

Just because your code works fine, and you wrote you are new to this, I just wanted to show you some alternative, shorter ways. ;)

```js
function unpack(str) {
  return [].concat.apply([], [].map.call(str, c => 
      [c.charCodeAt(0) >>> 8, c.charCodeAt(0) & 0xFF]
  ));
}

console.log(unpack('test'));
```

Or as one-liner:

```js
let unpack = str => [].concat.apply([], [].map.call(str, c => [c.charCodeAt(0) >>> 8, c.charCodeAt(0) & 0xFF]));
console.log(unpack('test'));
```

Answer (score -1):

A demonstration of functionality:

```js
function unpack(str) {
  var bytes = [];
  var len=str.length;
  for(var i = 0, n = len; i < n; i++) {
  var char = str.charCodeAt(i);
  bytes.push(char >>> 8, char & 0xFF);
  }
  return bytes;
}

console.log(unpack("no problem"))
```